# Specific user roles can't upload images anymore

Tags: wordpress, file

On our WordPress website we have 2 custom user roles (free_account & premium_account), which capabilities are set with the Members plugin.

Both user roles can add 'listings' (= a custom post type) via the frontend. This has been working fine for 4 years, but since last week those specific user roles can't upload images anymore. They receive the error message 'An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.'. Both user roles have been granted to upload files though.

All other user roles don't have this issue (admin, editor, author, contributor, ...). They can still upload files without any problem.

I tried a couple of things to fix the problem:

- increasing file size upload
- checking file permissions
- increasing php memory
- disabling plugins
- disabling Wordfence & replacing the .htaccess file

But unfortunately without any results.

What can I do the fix the issue? Maybe adding some custom code to grant extra capabilities?